# Cohomology of neighborhood of $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1$ in $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

Let $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1$ be embedded linearly to $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$ with $n>1$. (Such an embedding is given in coordinates by $[x:y]\mapsto [x:y:0:\dots: 0]$.)

> Is it true that for any open neighborhood $U$ (in the analytic topology) of $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1$ there exists a smaller neighborhood $V$ of the latter such that 
>   $$H^i(V, \mathcal{O})=0 \mbox{ for any } i>0,$$ 
>   where $\mathcal{O}$ is the structure sheaf?

Comment: There are arbitrarily small tubular neighborhoods that are disk bundles inside the normal bundle of $\mathbb{CP}^1$ relative to $\mathbb{CP}^n$.  You can apply the Leray spectral sequence for projection from the disk bundle to conclude the vanishing that you want.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that $E_2^{p,q}=0$ for $q>0$.? In that case how to show the vanishing of $H^1(\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1)$ with coefficients in the push forward under the projection of the structure sheaf?

Comment: I was wrong.  I forgot to dualize the normal bundle.  Please see Misha Verbitsky's post below.

Answer (score 6):

It is not hard to see that the
first cohomology is infinite-dimensional.

Take a complement $M:=CP^3 \ CP^1$
and consider a projection
$\pi:\; M \mapsto CP^1$. It is not
hard to see that $M$ is
isomorphic to the total space of
the bundle $O(1)^2$. The fibers
of $\pi$ are Stein, hence
$R^i\pi_*F=0$ for $i>0$ and any coherent sheaf
$F$, and cohomology $H^i(O_M)$ are the
same as $H^i(\pi_* O_M)$.

However, $\pi_* O_M= Sym^*(O(-1)^2)$,
because the regular functions on the
total space of $O(1)^2$ are $Sym^*(O(-1)^2)$.
However, $H^1(Sym^*(O(-1)^2))$ is
infinite-dimensional.

Same argument works for smaller
neighbourhoods $U\supset CP^1$, as
long as the fibers of $\pi:\; U \mapsto C P^1$
remain Stein.

Same is true for a neighbourhood of a 
rational line $C$ in a complex manifold 
if the normal bundle $NC$ is ample, 
but the proof is more complicated.

Comment: To make sure: when you say that the fibers are Stein, do you refer to a version of the base change theorem? Note that the morphism $\pi$ is not proper.

Comment: You don't need the base change theorem, just notice that the higher direct images vanish, because the projection is locally equivalent to a product with Stein fibers, and use it to compute the higher direct image explicitly